# Error Running autokeras Image Classifier Tutorial on Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, auto-keras

The autokeras tutorial here https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/autokeras/blob/master/docs/templates/tutorial/image_classification.ipynb

fails on the line:

```
import autokeras as ak

# Initialize the image classifier.
clf = ak.ImageClassifier(max_trials=10) # It tries 10 different models.
# Feed the image classifier with training data.
clf.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=3)
```

with error:

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:503 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:475 train_step  **
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:386 update_state
        self._build(y_pred, y_true)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:317 _build
        self._metrics, y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:1118 map_structure_up_to
        **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:1214 map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to
        *flat_value_lists)]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:1213 <listcomp>
        results = [func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_list,
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:1116 <lambda>
        lambda _, *values: func(*values),  # Discards the path arg.
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:416 _get_metric_objects
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:416 <listcomp>
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:437 _get_metric_object
        y_t_rank = len(y_t.shape.as_list())

    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Is this an error in the code or in the Google Colab setup?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, and make your question self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the code, I tried it myself on my local machine and it works perfectly. The real problem is this line

```
pip install tensorflow
```

This line gives `pip` full responsibility for choosing tensorflow version to install, sadly it chose to install the rc version `tensorflow-2.2.0rc1` which looks like it has a problem with `autokeras`.

So all you have to do to make this work is to fix the version to the latest stable tensorflow verison that is known to work with `autokeras`

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither pip install tensorflow==2.1.0 nor %tensorflow_version 2.x helped me. I am still getting the same error.

You would need exact 2.1 version as mentioned in the accepted answer above to get rid of the error.

I am using Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to install TensorFlow 2.1 again.

You can select it simply by calling:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I have TF 2.1.0 and still have the same error.
code running on my machine but not on google colab